# Recreate GitHub Network Graph in Java

Tags: github

I'm currently trying to recreate the GitHub Network Graph in Java as a school project. I'm using Kohsuke's Github-API to get all the data (repo, commits, etc...) and I actually got a prototype to work with some repositories out there, even though it's still not quite right.

My problem is getting the correct vertical spacing in the network graph.. My prototype is currently spacing the commits via some rules to detect merges/forks/branches but it's not working well with bigger and more complex repositories.

[Here](https://github.com/Youx/network-canvas) I found someone who recreated the old flash version of the network graph in JavaScript. But he is using a variable called "space" to determine the vertical spacing.
When I looked into the .js that creates the current Network Graphs I found that they also use a variable called space and spaceMap to get the spacing right.

It seems that without this variable it's not quite possible to make it look like the original Network Graph, but I didn't find the variable in Kohsuke's GitHub-API nor in GitHub's original API... But then again, I'm quite new to this GitHub-Story so maybe I'm just looking in the wrong places :/

If anyone tried to recreate the graph or knows how to find the spacing data I'd appreciate some hints.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for that insightful comment. I know that Java ≠ Javascript, but the link I added is Javascript plus the original network graph from GitHub is also in Javascript.

Comment: If your question is really about Java, put it in the tags and remove the javascript one. It is confusing the way that currently is.

Comment: If you read the text you'd know that my question is about the spacing variable of the github api. I only mentioned that I'm implementing it in Java.